# Images not showing up in Safari, but will show up in any other browser

Tags: javascript, image, browser, safari, cross-browser

My Images not showing up in Safari, but will show up in any other browser.

When I pull up the dev tools-- they are there, just not rendering to the page.

Hope someone can help me out:)[image]

Answer (score 0):

oh i see it's not https:// it must be https://cdn.img.facebook.org/ or else safari won't show it